# All floats round to 2 decimal places in PHP Web Application

Tags: php, web-applications

Is there a way to round off all the floating point values of a php web application to 2 decimal places?

I have completed developing a web application but while developing, I didn't consider precision of floating points and now my client wants them to be precised to 2 decimal places.

I know the one way of doing it is to use `round()` function everywhere wherever I have used floating point but I need to know a shortcut. Please help.

Comment: To my knowledge, no - there is no global attribute you can set to define this. You'll have to format the numbers individually.

Comment: There is no shortcut. PHP outputs whatyou tell it to. there's no global overrides. If you echo a float, php will output a float, and output exactly as it should be. if you want to change that output, you'll have to change the code EVERYWHERE you do that output.

Comment: @Qirel I hope there is, otherwise I will have to go through dozens of files, first searching for a floating variable and then rounding it off.

Comment: Sounds like you have a bit of work ahead of you then ;-) @ZohaibAslam

Comment: I found something like `ini_set('precision', 2);`, never used though. Can it help? @MarcB

Comment: might help, but seriously reconsider changing a system-wide setting to compensate for your design oversight. you'll have to test EVERYTHING else to make sure that changing the precision doesn't affect anything else.

Answer (score 1):

You can simple use PHP's `number_format`like so:

```
    <?php
        // FORMATTING AN INTEGER...
        $num            = 123;
        $formattedNum   = number_format( floatval($num), 2, '.', ''); // CAST  $num TO A FLOAT USING floatval();

        var_dump($formattedNum);     //<== PRODUCES: 123.00

        // FORMATTING A DOUBLE OR FLOATING POINT NUMBER...

        $num            = 123.4567890;
        $formattedNum   = number_format( floatval($num), 2, '.', '');

        var_dump($formattedNum);    //<== PRODUCES: 123.46
```

You could take it a bit further by creating a Petit Function that takes a Number as an Argument to handle that for you like so:

```
    <?php
        function roundOutNumber($number){
            try{
                $rounded = number_format(floatval($number), 2, '.', '');
            }catch(Exception $e){
                throw new Exception("Method takes only Numeric inputs.");
            }   
            return $rounded;
        }
```

And now if you have multiple $variables or even an array containing numeric data-types (int, float, double, long, etc), You can simply pass each numeric data to the function and in the case of an array; you could use the Function within a Loop like so:

```
    <?php
        $arrayOfNumbers = array(
            1234.5678,
            901.2345,
            67.8901,
            234.5678,
            901,
            2345
        );

        var_dump($arrayOfNumbers);

        foreach($arrayOfNumbers as $iKey=>&$numValues){
            $arrayOfNumbers[$iKey]  = roundOutNumber($numValues);
        }

        var_dump($arrayOfNumbers);
```

**1ST VAR_DUMP DISPLAYS THE ORIGINAL ARRAY:**

```
        array (size=6)
          0 => float 1234.5678
          1 => float 901.2345
          2 => float 67.8901
          3 => float 234.5678
          4 => int 901
          5 => int 2345
```

**2ND VAR_DUMP DISPLAYS:**

```
        array (size=6)
          0 => string '1234.57' (length=7)
          1 => string '901.23' (length=6)
          2 => string '67.89' (length=5)
          3 => string '234.57' (length=6)
          4 => string '901.00' (length=6)
          5 => string '2345.00' (length=7)
```

Confirm the Result [HERE.](https://eval.in/586395)

Comment: Actually I know how to do it for each individual variable but I want to know something which will do it for all variables without finding each floating variable separately.

Comment: @Zohaib Aslam   Don't know if the idea of encapsulating the above algorithm into a Function works for you. However, you may review the updated Post that illustrates the use of a simple Function in this regards...